# Is it possible to present a UIDocumentInteractionController for multiple items?

Tags: ios, ios7, uidocumentinteraction

The Photos app in iOS 7 allows you to select multiple photos, tap "Share" and be presented with a document interaction controller with the appropriate options for multiple items.

The Camera app goes one further and even updates the document interaction controller's options in real time as you select and deselect photos.

However, the UIDocumentInteractionController class seems only to allow for a single URL parameter.

Is it possible to do what the Photos and Camera apps do using public API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (void)showShareDialog
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:self.imgView.image.CGImage];

    NSArray* dataToShare = @[image, image2, image3];  // ...or whatever pieces of data you want to share.

    UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                      applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{

    }];

}
```

I think this should help

Comment: Will do ASAP -- apologies for the delay.

Comment: The UIActivityViewController works great for multiple items but it appears I still need to use a UIDocumentInteractionController for a single item if I want to include the "open in" options. I'd like to add an extra UIActivity for both single and multiple items. Are UIActivity and "open in" options effectively mutually exclusive?

Comment: No they are not, I think you should decide witch one to use before showing the dialog, UIActivityViewController is for sharing multiple items, while open in (UIDocumentationInteractionController) provides in-app support for managing user interactions with files in the local system, i.e. you have one url of the file that you want to share. @hatfinch

Comment: So if they're not mutually exclusive, how do I show a single, unified controller for a single file which allows for either opening that file in another app, or performing a custom UIActivity on that file?

Comment: Honestly, I like UIDocumentInteractionController more, because it shows more options then UIActivityViewCotnroller. Happy coding @hatfinch :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47675/discussion-between-hatfinch-and-basheer-cad)

Comment: You can have the bounty, anyway, for putting me onto UIActivityViewController. FWIW, I think Apple should deprecate UIDocumentInteractionController.

Answer (score 0):

Store the URLs of the selected items in an array. You can change the actions displayed depending upon the number of elements in the array. After the user makes his/her selection, you can loop through the URLs and apply the selected action.